# Why is my no-results.php template moving my sidebar and footer into the main container?

Tags: templates

I'm really stumped on this one but I'm hoping it's just another case of "It's late and you're missing something simple."

My `index.php` contains an `if` statement: If there are posts, run the loop and display them, else display the `no-results.php` template. For some reason, though, my `no-results.php` is breaking my layout by placing both the sidebar and footer inside of my `<main>` element where the content resides.

## PHP

Here is my `index.php` code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<!-- Content -->
<main id="content" class="grid">

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php
            /* Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
             * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
             * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
             */
                 get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
        ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php /* Post Navigation */ ?>
<?php mytheme_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'no-results', 'index' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

</main>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And here's my `no-results.php` code:

```
<?php /* This template shows a message when no search results are found */ ?>

<div class="grid">
    <header class="unit a-col-4 snug-bottom no-results">
        <h1><?php _e( 'No Results Found', 'clarity' ); ?></h1>
        <p class="post-meta"><?php _e( 'Please try a new search below.', 'mytheme' ); ?></p>
        <hr>
    </header>
</div>
<div class="grid">
    <div class="unit a-col-4 comfy-bottom">
        <?php get_search_form(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

## Generated Markup

For most of my templates, the generated markup looks like this:

```
<div class="hfeed">

    <div>
        <!-- Header -->
        <!-- Navigation -->
    </div>

    <main>
        <!-- Content -->
    </main>

    <div>
        <!-- Widget Area -->
    </div>

    <div>
        <!-- Footer -->
    </div>

</div>
```

When I search the blog and turn up no results (`no-results.php`), the generated markup looks like this instead:

```
<div class="hfeed">

    <div>
        <!-- Header -->
        <!-- Navigation -->
    </div>

    <main>
        <!-- Content -->
        <div>
            <!-- Widget Area -->
        </div>

        <div>
            <!-- Footer -->
        </div>
    </main>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean visually or they actually end up inside `main` container in page source? Can you provide example on live site?

Comment: @Rarst I mean sidebar() and footer() actually end up inside the `main` container, and only when `no-results` is used. I'll update my question with examples of generated markup. :)

Comment: Interesting development: I started a new server with a fresh WP install and the problem does not persist there. No changes to the code. Was it a caching issue or something? I'm using WAMP as my local dev environment.